# Is there a way to import Jira issues to GitHub?

Tags: github, jira

I've tried exporting issues from both GitHub and Jira to CSV files, but I've never tried exporting Jira issue then importing it to GitHub, is this possible? If so, what would be the best way to approach something like this?

Comment: Did you come up with a script to handle this? I'd also be interested in going this way

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I DID google a similar question and this was in the top 3 results. Shutting down good questions on SO because there are answers out there already is not always the best idea. Maybe this question was worded better, or because it's on SO it gets ranked higher by Google? For the rest of the internet who finds questions later, please don't be so hasty. It's very frustrating to Google something, see a VERY promising SO result near the top, and go to it, only to find it get shut down by someone like yourself. Thankfully another user answered the question in a more helpful way.

Answer (score 16):

There is simply not a "Import issues from JIRA" feature in GitHub.

The way I see it you have two options, either to integrate your current JIRA instance with GitHub or migrate the JIRA issues into GitHub issues using your own criteria and migration script.

**GitHub and JIRA Integration**

I would very much like to add all the instructions here but it's one of those cases where a [link to the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/customizing-your-github-workflow/github-extensions-and-integrations#project-management-tools) makes much more sense.

There's also a [video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCNWWfXpCw0) which is quite short and easy to follow.

**Migrating JIRA issues into GitHub Issues**

In order to do this you would have to write your own script that reads issues from  the [JIRA REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis) and creates new ones using [GitHub Issues REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue).

Note that JIRA and GitHub issues are different in nature, so your script would have to choose how to migrate one type of issue to another.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your documentation link is broken

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to export the JIRA issues as XML file.
The following project provides Python 2 scripts to import such a file into a GitHub project via its REST API:
https://github.com/hbrands/jira-issues-importer

Besides issues with comments, it imports milestones, labels and components as labels. References to issues in comments are to some degree converted. Also, JIRA relationships like "blocks" and "depends on" are migrated to special issue comments in GitHub.

It avoids the problem of running into abuse rate limits by using a special [Issue Import API](https://gist.github.com/jonmagic/5282384165e0f86ef105).

Please read the sections about the features, caveats, assumptions and prerequisites on the project site. Be sure to test the issue migration with a GitHub test project first.

Comment: Another similar project: https://github.com/doctrine/jira-github-issues

Comment: I needed to export all the JIRA issues to GitHub and jira-issues-importer did the trick, I wouldn't have found it if it weren't for this stackoverflow page. I had to make some modifications, add a few features and I updated it to work with Python 3.x as a bonus: https://github.com/ultimategrandson/jira-issues-importer

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things you need to do for export from JIRA and import to GitHub.

First export issues (to a csv file) from JIRA with the feilds you need.
Then read the csv file line by line and use the github api to create issue in GH.
https://github.com/susinda/github-client/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wso2/git/client/GitRestApiExecutor.java

Here is a sample client to do the job[1], readme contains the steps,feel free to modify it and use if that does not match with your requirement https://github.com/susinda/github-client

Answer (score 0):

Try this node module `https://github.com/gavinr/github-csv-tools`, need to download issue form Jira and use this to upload on GitHub.

Answer (score -3):

https://github.com/parcelLab/jira-to-github is a (pretty old) project to migrate JIRA issues to Github.

> 1. Export the issues from JIRA
>
>    First, create a full export to XML as described in this guide:
>      https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/exporting-issues-776636787.html
>
>    You'll need the exported entities.xml from JIRA to upload the
>      issues to your GitHub repository using the GitHub API.
> 2. Run the import to GitHub
>
>    Run node index.js to use the script

Comment: The parcelLab project no longer exists.